# Ubuntu 16.04. How to establish both internet and LAN connections at the same time

Tags: 16.04, networking, routing, nat

I have two network devices connected to my PC.

4G USB Stick(enx0c5b8f279a64) 192.168.8.1

Eth Adapter (enp0s10 192.168.50.20) is connected to a DIR-300 router(192.168.50.1).

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# 4g usb stick
auto enx0c5b8f279a64
        iface enx0c5b8f279a64 inet dhcp

# ethernet
auto enp0s10
        iface enp0s10 inet dhcp
```

Connections are configured by DHCP. I am able to gain access to both internet and LAN after fiddling with routes.

```
default         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    21     0        0 enx0c5b8f279a64
192.168.8.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    20     0        0 enx0c5b8f279a64
192.168.50.0    OpenWrt.lan     255.255.255.0   UG    11     0        0 enp0s10
OpenWrt.lan     *               255.255.255.255 UH    10     0        0 enp0s10
```

It all works. I can access both Internet and LAN. But there's a problem. Every query sent to internets gets stuck somwhere for a second or so. I mean there's a pause before every response. I thought that it's a problem with routing but traceroute shows that there're no excessive hops. It's just gateway->internet host.

```
traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (74.125.232.161), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.8.1 (192.168.8.1)  17.222 ms  17.166 ms  17.152 ms
 2  74.125.232.161 (74.125.232.161)  77.907 ms  82.239 ms  82.229 ms
```

I thought that DNS resolving is broken. But it's not. Same happening when I am trying to access something via ipv4 address.

When I ping google.com I get this wierd pause too, but the latency itself is okay(kinda, since that is 4G).

```
ping google.com
PING google.com (64.233.161.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lh-in-f113.1e100.net (64.233.161.113): icmp_seq=1 ttl=40 time=82.4 ms
64 bytes from lh-in-f113.1e100.net (64.233.161.113): icmp_seq=2 ttl=40 time=80.2 ms
64 bytes from lh-in-f113.1e100.net (64.233.161.113): icmp_seq=3 ttl=40 time=84.5 ms
64 bytes from lh-in-f113.1e100.net (64.233.161.113): icmp_seq=4 ttl=40 time=118 ms
64 bytes from lh-in-f113.1e100.net (64.233.161.113): icmp_seq=5 ttl=40 time=102 ms
```

It feels like some kind of forwarding is happening but I have it turned off and there're no configured NAT services. TBH I have no expertise in networking whatsoever.

My level of knowledge in this area can be described as "pressanykey".

PS. I am bad at English too.